# MVC: How to store common variables to get access from all MVC related files in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am learning MVC based web pages in php.I have few php files with multiple classes & methods in MVC layers.I have many variables & large arrays that need to be accessed in several files.some sample given below:

```
$label = array("lng"=>Language",tlabel"=>"Title", 
               "content"=>"Details", "tm"=>"Date", 
               "authr"=>"Post By");
$route_url;
$database;
$navbar_text;
$footer_text;
```

I saw few php example about using php keyword `global`. But using it in many parts of the code will become 
very messy to keep track.I also saw another technique where every common things goes inside a special class
called `Config` like given below:

```
// does it need auto load? i don't know
class Config
{

    public static $label = array("lng"=>Language","tlabel"=>"Title", 
                                   "content"=>"Details", "tm"=>"Date", 
                                   "authr"=>"Post By");
    public static $route_url;
    public static $database;
    public static $navbar_text;
    public static $footer_text;

}

echo SmtpConfig::$label["tlabel"];
```

So, please suggest the correct way in which MVC web developer do such things.Thanks

Comment: Cluttering up the global scope is considered bad practice, you might want to check out [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) instead.

Comment: That is not a good idea, it destroys the encapsulation of a class/object. Instead pass the data into the class as a parameter. Of the constructor if possible and save it as a property. Or as a parameter to a method if it is only required by that method

Comment: Don't call variable is coming from outside class and called from inside class, you can use a parameter in the function

Comment: Hands off from globals... use OOP properly

Comment: You can't.  That's how the language is designed.  The fact that you're using so many globals, however, should be a big red flag that there's something fundementally wrong with your design.  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Static Class Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

The second approach to use $GLOBAL vars.

But it is not a good approach to use a lot of global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using $GLOBALS super global array which is accessible throughout whole PHP script.

Add your variables in $GLOBALS super global array like,

```
$GLOBALS['data'] = 'Something';
```

and now you can access this variable globally like,

```
$something = $GLOBALS['data']
```